# Как считать русский текст из utf-8?

Tags: c++

Работаю в ubuntu. Имеется utf-8 файл, в котором записаны как русские, так и английские слова. Как корректно считать из него русские слова?

```
wfstream fin(_fileName);
if (!fin)
    throw std::exception();

wstring nextLine;

while(fin)
    getline(fin, nextLine);

fin.close();
```

`getline()` почему-то вообще не видит русских символов и читает только английские

Comment: Посмотрите на locale

Answer (score 2):

Если у Вас файл в UTF-8, то и используйте однобайтовые потоки ввода, а также однобайтовую `string`:

```
fstream fin(_fileName);
if (!fin)
    throw std::exception();

string nextLine;

while(fin)
    getline(fin, nextLine);

fin.close();
```

Теперь строки у Вас будут читаться корректно. Но это только начало Ваших проблем, а ничуть не их окончание. Как Вы собираетесь дальше работать с полученными данным? `std::string` это набор символов типа `char`, и этот класс ничего не знает об UTF-8.